# How to display rotated view (Layout) in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Without using image in background i want to display layout(which contains background color and Textview)  like this [image: rotated view]  you can see the box is slightly down at left side.

Can we achieve the same without using Rotation pragmatically ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add rotation to any View in layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your xml view

```
android:rotation="-5"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use xml parameter

```
android:rotation="30"
```

where integer in rotation is rotation degree